# How to update user profile in Django

Tags: python, django

I want to let my student to update his profile after he logged in, but I don't seem to be able to code the profile update properly. This is my code:

```js
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass


class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
```

```css
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'profile_edit' %}" class="" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Save</button>q
</form>
```

```html
def profile_edit(request):
    user = request.student
    form = StudentForm(request.POST or None, initial={'name': user.name,
                                                      'surname': user.surname})
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            user.student.name = request.POST['name']
            user.student.surname = request.POST['surname']

            user.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('index')

    context = {
        "form": form
    }

    return render(request, "registration/profile_edit.html", context)
```

Comment: What the error do you have? You should do `user = request.user` not `user = request.student`.

Comment: Yes. But I get error: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'name'. Thing is that Student extends the abstract user.

Comment: User is probably not authenticated. Try to add login_requered decorator to the view: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'name'` says that current user is not authenticated. You can make your view available only for authenticated users with [`login_required`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) decorator:

```
@login_required
def profile_edit(request):
    pass
```

Also User model dont have name attribute, you need to access user's student attribute to get it:

```
form = StudentForm(request.POST or None, initial={'name': user.student.name,
                                                  'surname': user.student.surname})
```

Comment: About that error. I forgot to log in. But now it shows: 'User' object has no attribute 'name'. Is that code good ?

Comment: Hm. It shows.. but I still need some tweaks . Would you like to move this to a discussion ?

Comment: What tweaks for example?

Comment: My student model had actually more fields, instead of just name and surname, all other fields show. Also, I cannot save just one field cuz others were required in my models.

Comment: Sorry I actually dont understand your problem. Can you post another question with details?

Comment: I can't post that often.. Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164004/discussion-between-dann-m-and-neverwalkaloner).

Answer (score 0):

I like this workaround a little bit more, you still need the login_required decorator.

In your models.py add

```
User.student = proberty(lambda p: Student.objects.get_or_create(user = p)[0])
```

Then in your views.py you can do something like:

```
student = request.user.student
if request.method != 'POST':       
    form = StudentForm(instance=student)

else:
    form = StudentForm(request.POST, instance=student)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the perfect answer for this question. Just paste in your views.py file, where you have handled your update profile.

```
    def handleUpdate(request, id):
if request.method == "POST":
    username=request.POST['username']
    email=request.POST['email']
    fname=request.POST['fname']
    lname=request.POST['lname']

    if len(username)<8:
        messages.error(request, "Your username must not be under 8 characters")
        return redirect('home')

    if len(username)>10:
        messages.error(request, "Your username must not be more than 10 characters")
        return redirect('home')

    myuser=User.objects.get(pk=id)
    myuser.first_name=fname 
    myuser.last_name=lname
    myuser.email=email
    myuser.username=username
    myuser.save()
    messages.success(request, "Your account has been updated successfully")
    return redirect('home')
```

Remember
1. email, fname & lname are the names of the form fields. Ensure that you put your form fields name.
2.`return redirect('home')` is defined in the urls.py as `views.home`. Ensure that you have replaced it with your views before running it.

----------------
The url for it in urls.py

```
    path(r'user/updateProfile/<int:id>', views.handleUpdate, name="handleUpdate")
```

----------------
The form's sction for it :

```
    action="/user/updateProfile/{{request.user.id}}" method="POST"
```

Remember : `user.id` only works when a user is logged in

Answer (score 0):

To handle this situation, you can override the clean_username method in your `UsersForm` class and customize the validation logic to suit your requirements. Here's an example of how you can modify your form to display a custom error message instead of the default validation error:

```
def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data['username']
        existval = User.objects.filter(username=username)
        if self.instance:
            existval = existval.exclude(pk=self.instance.pk)
        if existval.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("This username is already taken !!")
        return username
```