# Trying to update user information from 2 forms in Django

Tags: python, django

So I have a student model which inherits from AbstractUser. I used 2 forms in one view for registration since I needed email, name and surname to be in my student database (as well as other fields). Now I'm trying to make an update profile view, with 2 forms that I made especially for updating the info. But I think I'm getting it wrong.. might need a little help here. I need the student to be able to update his email (which is from User model) and his photo, phone, name and surname (which are in Student model).

```js
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'profile_edit' %}" class="" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

```css
def profile_edit(request):
    user = request.user
    form1 = UserEditForm(request.POST or None, initial={'email': user.email,
                                                        })
    form2 = StudentEditForm(request.POST or None, initial={'name': user.student.name,
                                                           'surname': user.student.surname,
                                                           'phone': user.student.phone,
                                                           'photo': user.student.photo})
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
            user.email = request.POST['name']
            user.student.name = request.POST['name']
            user.student.surname = request.POST['surname']
            user.student.phone = request.POST['phone']
            user.student.photo = request.POST['photo']
            user.save()
            return render(request, 'index.html')
    context = {
        "form1": form1,
        "form2": form2
    }
    return render(request, "registration/profile_edit.html", context)
```

```html
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    password = forms.CharField(label='Password', max_length=32, required=True, widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(label='Confirm', max_length=32, required=True, widget=forms.PasswordInput,
                                       help_text="Passwords must match!")

class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=True)
    surname = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=True)
    student_ID = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=14, min_length=14)
    photo = forms.ImageField(required=True)
    phone = forms.CharField(max_length=15, required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('name', 'surname', 'phone', 'student_ID', 'photo')


class UserEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email',)


class StudentEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    surname = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    photo = forms.ImageField(required=False)
    phone = forms.CharField(max_length=15, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('name', 'surname', 'phone', 'photo')
```

Problem is that I am getting no form, so I am either doing something wrong in the view, either the forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'profile_edit' %}" class="" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form1.as_p }}
    {{ form2.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

according to your context the names of your forms are `form1` and `form2`, so `form` only wont display any form

Comment: Yes. I was so blind, this is right. But now  I have a minor bug, my student model doesn't save anything actually now. And when I change the name, actually it replaces the email in User model.. some part of the view is messed up I think.

Comment: you have to save  your forms in your view hopefully you noticed that . added the following lines  form1.save() and form2.save()

Comment: @LeLouch after save it prompts me with: 1048, "Column 'user_id' cannot be null"

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two forms. I have answered your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48475039/how-to-update-user-profile-in-django) which led to this question.

It will save you from a lot of unnecessary Code.

Comment: I don't understand it.. it's quite much for me

Comment: Which part of my answer is causing problems?

Comment: I simply wish not to use that approach.

Comment: Ok, since I got no answers, I used your approach, but my user wouldn't get saved. Would you be kind to provide the code for this question ? Don't know exactly how to use this, as mentioned before.

Comment: Did you add an form.save() in the Else statement?

Comment: Yes. Surprisingly, this was exactly what I needed. But do you know how to store email in both models (User and Student). Now it gets updated only in User.

Comment: 1. According to your code you don't have a email field in the Student model
2. Why would you want to save it in Student if you saved it already in User. There you can access it.

Comment: I keep email in both, because I use email for password reset and I also use it to display profile info about student (I know it can be displayed from user as well, I just want the email to be visible in the database, since Im gonna restrict Staff to view users). Anyway, if I add an email filed to StudentEditForm, how do I change the view. This is it now: https://pastebin.com/MvgygCYV

Comment: What is the UserEditForm doing? Only setting a new E-Mail for the user?

What is the Student Model looking like?

Comment: You didn't answer my third question

Comment: Exactly like the student form. Just with user(onetoone to User) and email fields.

Comment: Then delete the UserEditForm and in your views do something like: user.email = form.email

Comment: I deleted UserEditForm and added email field to StudentEditForm and then I changed my views like this: https://pastebin.com/UKF6NHVJ  but I get error that  StudentEditForm object has no attribute 'email'

Comment: The error is exactly saying what is missing, an Email field. 
1) Does the Student Model have an Email field?
2) Did you add the email in the fields in the Meta Class of StudentEditForm?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164017/discussion-between-aokiji-and-dann-m).