# Updating user profile - Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I've created a template for updating account profiles using a Bootstrap snippet (from https://www.bootdey.com). With the django default format (like {{ form.as_p }}), updating accounts works (for example, when I modify the first name, it changes in the database). When I use the bootstrapp snippet, it doesn't update: it goes straight to 'homepage' without updating (as explained in views.py).

In forms.py

```
class EditAccountForm(UserChangeForm):

  class Meta:
      model = Account
      fields = ('email','first_name','last_name')
```

In views.py

```
def EditProfile(request):
  context= {}
  if request.POST:
    form = EditAccountForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        email = form.cleaned_data.get("email")
        raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        account = authenticate(email=email,password=raw_password)
        return redirect('profile_page')
    else:
        context['edit_form'] = form
        return redirect('homepage')
 else:
    form = EditAccountForm(instance=request.user)
    context['edit_form'] = form
 return render(request,'Account/edit_page.html',context)
```

the template: edit_profile.html (I only show the first_name part as example)

```
 <form method = "POST" class="form" novalidate="">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label>First name</label>
                          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="firstna"  value={{ edit_form.first_name.value }}>

                        </div>      
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col d-flex justify-content-end">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save Changes</button>
```

PS: I've preferred to use those snippets instead of the Django style since I find them more attractive and offer more freedom.

Answer (score 0):

Please check you are taking same value if you are changing the data in views like if you are using (name="firstna") in template so for First Name you have to take same in views.

Same question is asked here you can go and follow below link

[[How to update user profile in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48475039/how-to-update-user-profile-in-django])